# accessing all sub elements in list of list for every iteration

Tags: python

I Have list of list, I want to loop through the list and for every iteration i want to access the `ith` subelements of the list.

eg:

```
a = [[1, 3, 4], [2, 4, 4], [3, 7, 5]]
```

i want to do something like this

```
   for i in range(len(a)):
        x=a[i]
```

for 1st iteration I want to access the `0`th element from all the sub list (i.e) `1,2,3`

for 2nd iteration I want to access the `1`st element from all the sub list (i.e) `3,4,7`

I tried several approaches but failed, is there any trick to do that

Comment: What is your expected output? 123347?

Comment: the expected output is I want to loop through the list and for every iteration I want to access the i th element of the sublist and i will do some writing to a html file with the obtained data from each iteration

Answer (score 5):

You can use [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

```
s =  [[1, 3, 4], [2, 4, 4], [3, 7, 5]]
print zip(*s)
#[(1, 2, 3), (3, 4, 7), (4, 4, 5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_column(n, table):
    result = []
    for line in table:
        result.append(line[n])
    return result

test = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

for i in range(len(test[0])):
    print(get_column(i, test))
```

Execution :

```
[1, 4, 7]
[2, 5, 8]
[3, 6, 9]
```

Comment: I suggest you to accept the response so.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in above answer you can use an elegant way with `zip` but **if you want to access to the columns in every iteration and dont want to get all of them in one time** `itertools.izip` is what you are looking for , `itertools.izip` return a generator that you can get the result in every iteration  :

```
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> for i in izip(*a):
...  print i
... 
(1, 2, 3)
(3, 4, 7)
(4, 4, 5)
```

Also you can use `pop` in a `for` loop (less performance than `izip`):

```
>>> a = [[1, 3, 4], [2, 4, 4], [3, 7, 5]]
>>> test=[]
>>> for i in range(len(a[0])):
...   for j in a:
...    test.append(j.pop(0))
...   print test
...   test=[]
... 
[1, 2, 3]
[3, 4, 7]
[4, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative for the zip method,

```
>>> a = [[1, 3, 4], [2, 4, 4], [3, 7, 5]]
>>> new_list = []
>>> for k,v in enumerate(a):
...     new_list.append([])
...     for item in a:
...             new_list[-1].append(item[k])
... 
>>> new_list
[[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 7], [4, 4, 5]]
```